# grep multiple patterns when the variable has multiple strings

Tags: shell, grep

How do I grep multiple patterns in a variable which contains multiple strings?

```
words=(hello world foo bar)
grep -e ${words}  text.txt
```

Also, I will be using `words` as a variable where all user inputs will be saved. Is there any way I can change the format of the variable so it can be used to grep all the strings inside?

The problem is that when I try the code above, I get all the results from `text.txt` regardless of them meeting the grep command.

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? Lines on which _all_ words are found or lines on which _any_ of the words is found? Also, what operating system are you using (that tells us what flavor of `grep` you have)?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/648218/72456

Comment: I'm looking for all files which contain any of the given word sort of like an or operator. i'm using ubuntu in WSL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words=(hello world foo bar)
grep -F -f <(printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}") text.txt
```

This uses [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to provide a "file" containing each word on its own line.  The `-f` option tells `grep` to read its list of patterns to match from a file.

The `-F` option tells `grep` that the patterns are fixed strings, not regular expressions.  This speeds up the pattern matching.  If the words do happen to be regexes, remove this option.